# magento update admin user details programmatically

Tags: magento

I am creating a admin user using my code. But initially i am saving it as a inactive user. That is working fine. Then later i need to edit that admin user record (programmatically) i only need to change the is_active value into one, just to make my admin user active. So i tried below code:

```
$email = 'abc@test.com';
    Mage::getModel('admin/user')
                            ->loadByUsername($email)
                            ->setIsActive(1)
                            ->save();
```

Here i am filtering data using user name. When i run this is_active value is getting changed as i need. But at the same time, the password field also getting changed. Can anyone tell me why it is happening and what i can do to solve this issue.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. According to the question i am filtering data using loadByUsername($email). But i changed my code as in below;

```
$email = 'abc@test.com';
$userByEmail = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->getCollection()
                ->addFieldToFilter('email', array('eq' => array($email)));

foreach ($userByEmail as $uByEmail) {
   $userId = $uByEmail['user_id'];
}

$user = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->load($userId);
        $user->setIsActive(1)
        ->save();
```

As per the code, i retrieved the user_id  using the known email address. And then load data using that user_id. And then saved value.

This way solved my issues :)